# Wordpress /htaccess redirect: www one page, non-www another

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to send www traffic for a specific page one place, and send non-www traffic for a specific page to another. I can find how to do this for all pages, but anything I try page-specific does not work. I made sure to place the rules before the Wordpress block in htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/help$ http://example.com/contact [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^http://example.com/help$ http://example.com/buy [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly states that a `RewriteRule` works on the *path* of a requested URL, not on the full URL. So you need to combine the rule with a `RewriteCond` where you can evaluate the requested *host* of the URL:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?help/?$ http://example.com/contact [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?help/?$ http://example.com/buy [R=301,L]
```

That example works in the central http server's host configuration (which is the preferred location to implement such rules) but also in a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess" file) which has to be located inside the http host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. Also you need to enable such rules in distributed configuration files by means of the `AllowOverride` directive.

Refer to the documentation for details, that should *always* be your first stop to answer questions. As typical for OpenSource projects it is of excellent quality and comes with good examples:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

And a side note: your examples use the unencrypted `http` protocol. That really is a thing of the past. Any official project should definitely use the encrypted `https` protocol these days. SSL certificates are free of charge these days ...